# Create regex of string

Tags: java, regex

I have input string which I want to convert to regex and then compare against another string.

```
String inputString = "https://*.mlc.net/Gateway/api/Transmissions/State (body 0 bytes)";

String strToMatch = "https://abc.mlc.net/Gateway/api/Transmissions/State (body 0 bytes)";
```

I have done it like:

```
String regex = inputString.replace("*", "(.*)");

strToMatch.matches(regex)
```

but it fails. Can someone please explain the code?

I know backslashes are required before paranthesis but would require code which will work for all characters in the input string.

Comment: You also need to escape the characters that have a meaning in a regexp.

Comment: In your input string '(' and ')' should be escaped. `inputString = "https://*.mlc.net/Gateway/api/Transmissions/State \\(body 0 bytes\\)";` should work for the given example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match because there are some regex metacharacters in your input string. Namely, the regex engine interprets the parentheses around `body 0 bytes` as a capture group instead of literal parentheses. You want everything in the input string to be matched *literally*, except the `(.*)` parts, right?

You can split the input string with `*`, then for each part, call `Pattern.quote` to escape all the regex meta characters. Finally, you join the parts together with `(.*)`:

```
private static String createRegex(String inputString) {
    String[] parts = inputString.split("\\*");
    return Arrays.stream(parts).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("(.*)"));
}
```

Comment: Right, but can you please confirm if this will work for all characters in the input string which have meaning in regex?

Comment: @user3770039 Yes it will, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thanks, will this work if input string does not contain *?

Comment: @user3770039 Yes, it will create a regex that matches exactly the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to escape the characters that have a meaning in a regexp:

```
    String regex = formatRe(inputString);
```

...

```
private static String formatRe(String inputString) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c: inputString.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case '*':
                buf.append("(.*)");
                break;
            case '.':
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '[':
            case ']':
                // ...
                buf.append('\\');
                buf.append(c);
                break;
            case '\t':
                buf.append("\\t");
                break;
            default:
                buf.append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```